# Magento 2 : Price Layer Navigation Automatic equalize product count not working

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.3, magento-2-commerce

When configure with Backend Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Layered Navigation  configured for the Automatic (equalize product count).

That wasn't working with vanilla Magento. Please find attached screenshots.
[image: Admin configuration for the equalize product count]

[image: Front Layer navigation]